# ANTLR grammar for multi-level text segmentation

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I want to create a grammar that will parse a text file and create a tree of levels according to configurable "segmentors". This is what I have created so far, it kind of works, but will halt when a "segmentor" appears in the beginning of a text. For example, text "and location" will fail to parse. Any ideas?

Also, I'm pretty certain that the grammar could be greatly improved, so any suggestions are welcome.

```
grammar DocSegmentor;

@header {
package segmentor.antlr;
}

// PARSER RULES
levelOne: (levelTwo LEVEL1_SEG*)+ ;

levelTwo: (levelThree+ LEVEL2_SEG?)+ ;
levelThree: (levelFour+ LEVEL3_SEG?)+ ;
levelFour: (levelFive+ LEVEL4_SEG?)+ ;
levelFive: tokens;

tokens: (DELIM | PAREN | TEXT | WS)+ ;


// LEXER RULES
LEVEL1_SEG  : '\r'? '\n'| EOF ;
LEVEL2_SEG  : '.' ;
LEVEL3_SEG  : ',' ;
LEVEL4_SEG  : 'and' | 'or' ;

DELIM   :  '`' | '"' | ';' | '/' | ':' | '’' | '‘' | '=' | '?' | '-' | '_';
PAREN   :  '(' | ')' | '[' | ']' | '{' | '}' ;

TEXT    : (('a'..'z') | ('A'..'Z') | ('0'..'9'))+ ;
WS      : [ \t]+ ;
```

Comment: Do those segmentors require to be configured at runtime? If yes I'd go with a parser combinator as those libraries are very flexible.

Comment: Yes I think that would be very useful. Do you have any suggestions for Java/Scala?

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely go with a Scala parser combinator library.

https://lihaoyi.github.io/fastparse/
https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators

Those are just two examples for a library you can write by hand with little effort and tune to whatever you need. I should mention that you should go with Scalaz (https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) if you're writing a parser monad on your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll definitely look into that. The question for ANTLR still holds though.

Comment: @spyk Yeah sure. It's just an alternative to what you're trying. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a parser at all for that task. All you need is keyword spotting.

It's much easier and more flexibel if you just scan your text for the "segmentators" by walking over the input. This also allows to handle text of any size (e.g. by using memory mapped files) while parsers usually (ANTLR for sure) load the entire text into memory and tokenize it fully, before it comes to parsing.

Comment: That's a fair point, and it's what I have been using so far pretty successfully. I want however to be able to support more complex constructs such as nested parenthesis and other language constructs, but things got out of hand with the manual code complexity, that's why I have been looking to move to parsers.